# How to set filepath of downloads API to remember last location

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

When download a file through code such as follows, the file chooser usually opens to the location of the last download.

```
           let elem = window.document.createElement('a'),

               url = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob_data );

           elem.href = url;

           elem.download = fileName;        

           document.body.appendChild(elem);

           elem.click();        

           document.body.removeChild(elem);

           elem = null;

           window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Is there a way to get the downloads.download() function of the web extensions download API to open to the last location also, instead of always the default downloads directory, so that the user doesn't have to repeatedly select a new location from there.

I know that the filename option in downloads.download() doesn't give such an option, but thought that there might be a way to do so in the extension API since the regular web page remembers the last download location.

Thank you.

Comment: Currently it's not possible, if you want to have this feature follow this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1395207

Comment: See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1342563